# What does this snippet work? It uses session cookie

Tags: cakephp, session-cookies

My website is a gadget application. It uses CakePHP framework. It has the below snippet in AppController::beforeFilter(). I searched the cookie variable in the project but can't find any other occurences. **I also don't understand what it works**. **Why does it always check this in every request**.

```
    if ( isset( $_COOKIE[session_name()] ) ) {
        if ( !isset( $this->sns_id ) ) {
            // セッション期限切れ
            $this->cakeError( 'session' );
        }               
    }
    else {
        // スタートページからの遷移でなかったら               
        if ( !isset( $_REQUEST['post_pf_params'] ) ) {
            $this->cakeError( 'cookie' );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [CakePHP api](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html),

> Controller::beforeFilter()
>
> This function is executed before every action in the controller. It’s a handy place to check for an active session or inspect user permissions.

So Here is what it does,

```
// checks if a cookie exists with current session name
if ( isset( $_COOKIE[session_name()] ) ) {
    // if $this->sns_id does not exists show a session error
    if ( !isset( $this->sns_id ) ) {
        $this->cakeError( 'session' );
    }               
} else {
    // otherwise if  there is not request parameter with name post_pf_params is sent
    // show a cookie error.
    if ( !isset( $_REQUEST['post_pf_params'] ) ) {
        $this->cakeError( 'cookie' );
    }
}
```

---

From google translation,

セッション期限切れ means *Session expired*.
スタートページからの遷移でなかったら means *If you are not a transition from the Start Page*